# Gnuplot HPGL with HP7470a plotter change label size

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to change the label size for a plot on a HP7470a pen plotter. This is a economical version of the HP7475a with only 2 pens. There does not seem to be an option in the terminal to change the label size. How do I get my labels to be bigger than just a few millimetres?

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any provision for changing the font size in any of the gnuplot HP printer drivers.  They and the printers they support date back to the 1980s when pen plotters were state-of-the-art and gnuplot haad only reached version 1 or 2. The drivers have been carried forward for decades but largely ignored when gnuplot gained additional capabilities for managing font selection, text markup, etc in version 4.

Some time during gnuplot version 4.4 (~2010) the terminal option `fontscale` was added for new terminals and backported for some of the then-current terminals.  But the pen plotter drivers were not included in that set of updates, probably because no users were asking for it and the developers may not have had the relevant hardware to test it on.

I think it would be easy enough to add support for this option to the hpgl terminal, but I don't have a plotter to test it on.  If you are willing to test and report back, then please open a Feature Request on the [gnuplot tracker site](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/) and discussion can continue there.

**Update**

With the assistance and testing of Quad, support for font scaling on HPGL printers has been added to the gnuplot development version and will in the next release (5.4.5).

Comment: Thanks Ethan, I will submit a Feature Request.

Comment: Ethan I have submitted a feature request.